# Transform object to object where "equal" property exists to the value of "equal"

Tags: lodash

I have a deep object like `cats` below, and I'm looking for a simple way to remove all properties deeply where the nested property is set to `equal`.

```
const cats = {
  love: {
    meow: {
      equal: 2,
    },
    dolphin: {
      hi: 'meow',
    },
    doggo: true,
    soup: undefined,
    vampire: {},
    deep: {
      ocean: {
        love: {
          equal: 'hi',
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

To this:

```
const cats = {
  love: {
    meow: 2,
    deep: {
      ocean: {
        love: 'hi',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @OriDori's answer I customized it to not set empty / unwanted props.

```
const fn = collection => lodash.transform(collection, (r, v, k) => {
  if (lodash.isPlainObject(v)) {
    if (lodash.has(v, 'equal')) {
      r[k] = lodash.get(v, 'equal');
    } else {
      const d = fn(v);
      if (lodash.size(d)) {
        r[k] = d;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive [`_.transform()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#transform):

```js
const cats = {
  love: {
    meow: {
      equal: 2,
    },
    dolphin: {
      hi: 'meow',
    },
    doggo: true,
    soup: undefined,
    vampire: {},
    deep: {
      ocean: {
        love: {
          equal: 'hi',
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

const fn = (collection) => _.transform(collection, (r, v, k) => {
  if(_.isArray(v)) r[k] = fn(v);
  else if (_.isObject(v)) {
    if(_.has(v, 'equal')) r[k] =  _.get(v, 'equal');
    else {
      const value = fn(v);
      if(!_.isEmpty(value)) r[k] = value; 
    }
  } else if(!_.isUndefined(v)) r[k] = v;
});

const result = fn(cats);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey, this is not returning what is expected. It is assigning `equal` to the parent value, but it is not getting rid of the unwanted properties.

Comment: Added checks to clear empty objects, and undefined values. If you want to ignore `null` values as well, change `_.isUndefined()` to `_.isNill()`.

Comment: btw - you could have edited an answer directly instead of opening a new one.